# Mongod server wont start

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I followed mongodb official installation guide to the letter from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
Things I tried till now

1. removing and reinstalling mongodb
2. trying to use mongodb ubuntu package (mongod server wont start in that too with output mongod.service does not exist)

here is the output I am getting

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.760+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":5972,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"GL62"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: check if you have sufficient permission on **/tmp** as logs indicate some permission issue on socket file. or seems earlier, mongodb started with root user. 

"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock",**"error":"Operation not permitted"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `s` field in each log object is the severity of the message: I = informational, W = warning, E = Error.

If you look for the first error in that log, you will see it is:

```
{
   "t":{"$date":"2021-04-13T13:09:20.763+05:30"},
   "s":"E", 
   "c":"NETWORK", 
   "id":23024, 
   "ctx":"initandlisten",
   "msg":"Failed to unlink socket file",
   "attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}
}
```

Which is a file permissions problem.

You will need to fix the permissions on the noted file.

Comment: Thank you, I found what was not working, reinstalled it with force using a .deb file and install the mongo shell separately.